# Modeling floor function exactly

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, modeling, linearization

Suppose we want to enforce a constraint
$$
y=\lfloor{x}\rfloor
$$
where $x$ is some continuous variable. One option is to use
$$
x-1\leq{y}\leq{x},\quad y\in\mathbb{Z},
$$
which fails on the edge case $x\in\mathbb{Z}$. One way around this which works approximately is to introduce some tolerance $\varepsilon>0$ and enforce
$$
x-1+\varepsilon\leq{y}\leq{x},\quad y\in\mathbb{Z},
$$
which fails if $x\in(\lceil{x}\rceil-\varepsilon,\lceil{x}\rceil)$. Is there an exact way to enforce a floor function, perhaps by introducing additional integer variables?

Comment: My answer is incorrect. I've been trying to salvage it but haven't figured out how yet. You should un-accept my answer, and I will delete it. I'll post a new one if I ever figure it out.

Comment: @LarrySnyder610 Oh too bad! I’ll keep my eye out

Comment: On the plus side, looks like I'll earn my [Disciplined badge](https://or.stackexchange.com/help/badges/37/disciplined).

Comment: As one answer shows, you can easily do this when you can enforce a strict inequality over continuous variables. Your $\varepsilon$ trick looks like a way to work around not being able to do that. It might be a good idea to indicate if strict inequalities don't work for you, if that is indeed the case.

Comment: If you want to use this in a solver you'll have to work with the (carefully chosen) epsilon approach as it is not possible (due to machine precision) to have a real " strictly less than" constraint - only "less or equal" than constraints are meaningful.

Comment: Similar question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1862885/linear-program-with-ceiling-or-floor-functions

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is not possible to model the floor function as a constraint without modeling strict inequality. To prove this, I will show how the floor function can be used to model strict inequalities.

*Thanks to @Rob Pratt for showing a cleaner formulation that does not need a possibly large M*.

Suppose we can model the constraint $y=\lfloor x\rfloor$ for any real variable $x$ and integer variable $y$. First note that if we have the floor over the real numbers, we have the ceiling as well, since $\lceil x\rceil = -\lfloor -x\rfloor$. This means we can add constraints $\lceil x\rceil -\lfloor x\rfloor =1$, which is equivalent to $x\notin \mathbb{Z}$. The statement $0<x$ for a real variable $x$ is equivalent to $0\leq x \wedge (1\leq x \vee x\notin \mathbb{Z})$. So, we can encode the statement $0<x$ as follows:

$\begin{align*}0&\leq x\\
 1-M\cdot (1-b_1)&\leq x\\
b_2 &= \lceil x\rceil -\lfloor x\rfloor\\
 b_1 + b_2&\geq 1,
\end{align*}$

However, since $x$ is required to be positive in all cases, we can set $M$ to $1$ to obtain the following formulation:

$\begin{align*}b_1&\le x \\ b_2 &= \lceil x \rceil - \lfloor x \rfloor \\ b_1 + b_2 &\ge 1\end{align*}$

using only the additional binary variables $b_1,b_2$. As any strict inequality can be modeled via $0<x$, we are done.

In other words, if we assume we cannot model strict inequalities, then we cannot model a floor function.

---

Intuitively, what is going on here is that the floor function constraint is as 'powerful' as strict inequalities or integrality testing. Or, to speak in CS terms, all these constraints can be reduced to each-other and lie in the same equivalence class. (cf. complexity classes and poly-time reductions) I wonder if someone investigated these 'expressibility classes' in the context of linear programming before.

---

@Rob Pratt notes that we can even do without the additional binary variables and write the constraint $0<x$ as the single constraint $1-\lceil x\rceil + \lfloor x \rfloor \leq x$. However, note that even after removing the binary variables this reduction still only makes sense in the context of *integer* programming, as flooring an otherwise unconstrained real variable yields an unconstrained integer variable.

Comment: Conjunctive normal form of your logical proposition leads to the following slightly simpler formulation: \begin{align*} 0 &\le x \\ 1 - M \cdot(1-b_1)&\le x \\ b_3 &= \lceil x \rceil - \lfloor x \rfloor \\ b_1 + b_3 &\ge 1\end{align*}

Comment: And then taking $M=1$ simplifies further: \begin{align*} b_1&\le x \\ b_3 &= \lceil x \rceil - \lfloor x \rfloor \\ b_1 + b_3 &\ge 1\end{align*}

Comment: @RobPratt Ah yes, you are right, we don't even need big-M when we already require x is positive. That dependency on big-M did seem weird. This makes it a lot cleaner, thanks!

Comment: This is nice. I have to think about it a bit more but I think I am convinced.

Comment: In fact, I guess we can eliminate the binary variables and just have $$1-\lceil x \rceil +\lfloor x \rfloor \le x.$$

Comment: @RobPratt, would you say please, is there any way to linearize the floor/ceil function without using integer variables? I mean for example by an LP?

Comment: @A.Omidi floor and ceiling are not convex and so cannot be modeled with LP.

Comment: @RobPratt, thank you so much. 

Comment: @RobPratt, would you say please, what are the two new variables $ \lceil x \rceil - \lfloor x \rfloor$ meaning, and how should be defined in the model? Are those new positive variables with an upper and lower bound on the original variable $x$? Is there any implementation on it to clarify coding such constraints?

Comment: @A.Omidi This answer begins by supposing that a new variable $y$ can be introduced with linear constraints to represent $\lfloor x \rfloor$ and then examines the implications of that assumption.

Comment: @RobPratt, thanks, but I am not sure understanding what proposed in the answer. Is there any relation between $y$ and the constraints you pointed out in the comments?

Comment: Yes, $y=\lfloor x \rfloor$.

Answer (score 9):

I think you can resort to **bilevel optimization**, in the spirit of slide 3 [here](http://www.dei.unipd.it/~fisch/papers/slides/2017%20Sorrento%20%5bFischetti's%20plenay%20on%20Bilevel%5d.pdf)

In bilevel optimization, some variables are the optimal solutions of another optimization problem called "the follower subproblem".

In our case, one can define the following follower subproblem:

$$y = \underset{y'}{\operatorname{argmax}} \left\{ y': y' \le x, \ y' \hbox{ integer} \right\}$$

This should work also if $x=(x_1, \dots\,x_n)$ is an $n$-dimensional vector, i.e., you can set-up a *single* follower problem to define all the rounded $y_i$'s:

$$y = \underset{y'}{\operatorname{argmax}}\left\{ \sum_{i=1}^n y'_i: y' \le x, \ y' \hbox{ integer}\right\}$$

Whether this is useful in practice I don’t know.

Comment: How is this exact given non-zero achieved integrality (etc.) tolerances?

Comment: Well, the question asked for an exact formulation without tolerances, as the bilevel one. I agree that solving in practice that formulation brings tolerances back (see the last line in my answer) but I doubt you can get anything practical without tolerances and/or assumptions on x.

Comment: I think this approach works. It is *much* harder to solve than introducing new binary variables, big-Ms, etc., as you pointed out, but I think this answer also makes sense in light of @Discrete lizard's answer, i.e., that floor is somehow fundamentally harder than, say, other logical constraints.

Comment: @LarrySnyder610 Or in particular, that it is about as hard as modeling a strict inequality, which via my answer + this answer can also be done with bi-level optimisation. In that way, you can interpret this differently as follows: solving bi-level optimisation is at least as hard as solving ILP with strict constraints. In other words, this approach works for _modeling_ the problem, but it probably isn't very useful for actually _solving_ the problem.

Comment: @Discrete lizard If all we want to do is "model" the problem, we can use the "floor" function, which exactly models the floor function. It is then up to the modeling language or solver how to (approximately) implement the floor function. For instance, YALMIP overloads the MATLAB floor function https://yalmip.github.io/command/floor/ , so that takes care of the (exact) "modeling". YALMIP uses mixed integer to convert this to the problem provided to the solver, which of course is not exact.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone Yes, specific modelling languges can define all sorts of extensions to the 'standard models' (e.g. MILP etc.) I think this question is mainly about expressibility within "exact MILP", not within a particular solver language. I guess my usage of the term 'model' could also be too restrictive here.

Answer (score 7):

As all have mentioned, the problem is intrinsically hard, as it effectively involves a strict inequality.

One way to represent it, using no strict inequalities or magic constants, is to use the simple trick that $> 0$ can be replace with $\geq e^{-z}$ for a new decision variable $z$. An exact solver (not allowed to work with infinities) could then never return a non-strict solution.

Here, that would translate to $x-1 + e^{-z} \leq y \leq x$. Nice convex exponential cone relaxation and all.

Of course, a practical exact solver would not be able to work exactly with expressions involving exponentials, so this is just silly acrobatics trying to avoid introducing some kind of tolerance in the end, i.e., a magic constant.

EDIT: A solution which (in theory...) can be implemented and wouldn't force you out in the transcendental world is to use $x-1 + z^{-2} \leq y \leq x$

Comment: Fair point re: the practical solver, but I like this clever trick

Answer (score 3):

$x-1 <y \leq x \implies y \leq x < y+1\implies 0\leq x-y  <1$. We then can set $y\in \mathbb {Z} $.

Comment: With the "strictly less than" constraint you'll run into problems when implementing this in a real model to be solved with a solver. You'll then have to do the epsilon trick that was already mentioned in the question.

Comment: $x-1 +\epsilon \leq y \leq x\implies y \leq x \leq y+1-\epsilon\implies0\leq x-y  \leq1-\epsilon$. The same argument as the above answer, working for solvers, @Jakob.

Comment: If $x=1-\epsilon$ then $y=0$ is not correct?

Comment: sorry, my mistake... Had ceil and not floor function in mind...
Does this also work if $x<0$ (especially the corner cases with $x\pm\varepsilon<0$)?

Comment: In linear programming, we cope with $x\leq 0$ by introducing $x'=-x $. Everything will change accordingly.

Comment: I know that. But I'm still not convinced. Suppose $x=1-\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ then $y$ has to be $1$ (as $1-\frac{\varepsilon}{2}>1-\varepsilon$), but it should be $0$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94921/discussion-between-jakobs-and-majid-salavati-khoshghalb).

Comment: Now, I understand your point. But the relation with $\epsilon  $ works well with solvers, because in solvers we define the precision. For instance, if the precision is 4 we can have 0.9999 but never 0.99995. And we can take $\epsilon  $ here 0.0001 and everything works.

Answer (score 3):

You only specified $x$ is "continuous". I'll interpret this as $x$ is rational rather than real. This is not a terrible assumption, as floating point numbers in computers are rational anyways.

A rational $x$ can be replaced by a fraction of two integers $x = \frac{p}{q}$ with $p$ free and $q$ positive.

Now the constraint is $y = \left\lfloor \frac{p}{q}\right\rfloor$. This is equivalent to the two constraints

\begin{cases}y = \frac{p - m}{q}\\m = p \mod q\end{cases} where $m$ is another integer variable.

Let's introduce yet another (non-negative) integer variable $a$ and additional constraints to get rid of modulo operator.
\begin{cases}p = a \cdot q + m\\m \leq q - 1\end{cases}

So finally we can replace the constraint $y = \lfloor x \rfloor$ by

\begin{cases}x = \frac{p}{q}\\y = \frac{p-m}{q}\\p = a \cdot q + m\\m \leq q - 1\end{cases} where $p$ is a free integer and $a,m,q$ are positive integers.

Of course, this is no longer linear and quite ugly to solve. In implementations it will bring tolerances back when approximating the nonlinear constraints.

Comment: Floating point numbers are not rational. In particular, rationals allow for exact operations, which can be implemented as long as you can represent large enough integers, while floating points are not exact. It is correct that floating points have finite precision, but they are not rationals.

Comment: Maybe I should have added that by "floating point numbers" I mean floats according to IEEE754. Any number re-presentable by a float or double in your favorite programming language is rational.

Comment: Seems like another clever trick, although at the cost of new kinds of unpleasantness.

Comment: @MichaelFeldmeier Hmm. While I would agree that floats (IEEE754 or not) themselves can be equally well considered to be an implementation for rationals as for reals, I personally would expect exact representation and arithmetic when people talk about 'rationals', though. Still, this is only a digression, it doesn't really matter for this answer whether floats are rational or not.

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer of Rob can be developed into an exact answer, if we can ascertain apriori that the fractional part $s$ can be no larger than a given bound.

Consider $x$ to be the floor  of $y$. Further assume we can guarantee that $x$ does not lie in the following range (Integer + $\delta$, Integer+1] for any Integer. This assumption can be stated also as: $0 \le \delta <1$ is the largest possible value for the fractional part of $x$. Of course this is a hard condition to satisfy, but for many problems it can be easy. For example, consider this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3520916/proof-for-an-easy-empirical-result-on-fractions-and-ceilings

Then $x-\delta \le y \le x$ and $y \in Z^+$ model the floor exactly.

Answer (score 1):

[It](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) is solved by introducing a [slack variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slack_variable), one simple explanation is [here](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2016/03/ceiling-function-in-mixed-integer.html) and a more detailed video tutorial is [here](http://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/SlackVariables) (with online solver).

Alternative (homework preventing) example:

> How to implement the [Ceiling function](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2016/03/ceiling-function-in-mixed-integer.html) in a Mixed Integer Program model.
>
> The constraint in question is:
>
> $$\left\lceil\frac{x - A}{B}\right\rceil \cdot C + D \cdot x \lt E$$
>
> Answer:
>
> Introduce an integer variable $y$ and a continuous slack variable $s$ and write:
>
> \begin{align}y \cdot C + D \cdot x &\leq E\\y&=\frac{x-A}{B}+s\\s &\in [0,0.999]\\y &\in \{\dots,−3,−2,−1,0,1,2,3,\dots\}\end{align}
>
> Note that $\lt$ constraints are no good, so we make that $\leq$. We have a very small area for $s$ that we don’t allow: between $0.999$ and $1$. This is to prevent that the ceiling of an integer $k$ is the next integer $k+1$.

Comment: The constraint you mention differs from the one in the question, which is $y=\lfloor x\rfloor$. In fact, the constraint $\lceil a\rceil< b$ in this answer is equivalent to $a\leq b-1$. (perhaps you meant to write $\leq$ there) The question also asked for exact methods to deal with this problem, not some finite tolerance (here $0.001$).

Comment: No, follow the link; it is transcribed correctly.

Comment: I see. Then your linked source is incorrect. I've noted it on their answer on [math.se](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1679654/) Also, first be sure to indicate verbatim copied text with a quote block, so that we can see what text is yours and what is written elsewhere.

Comment: DL, I saw your post in chat, perhaps this helps: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1606358/how-to-prove-ceiling-and-floor-inequality-more-formally?rq=1#comment3274917_1606439 - That site is [difficult to earn rep on](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/514699/discrete-lizard), even for people with 100K+ [that site is hard to earn rep on, and incorrect information is punished](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7694636#7694636) (conversation is a bit lengthy).

Comment: @Rob I agree with DL, in that the question (and my bounty) are looking for an exact method that doesn't require a finite tolerance. Otherwise, I think your approach is similar to the one in the OP and in the answer by Majid Salavati-Khoshghalb. (Somewhat different formulation, but same basic idea.)

Comment: @Rob After discussion on that post, it turns out that my above claim that $a\leq b-1$ would work is incorrect. The point about the tolerance still remains, as LarrySnyder610 also notes.

Comment: @DavidM. See also: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/floor and [using an epsilon](https://mortoray.com/2016/01/05/the-trouble-with-floor-and-ceil/).

Comment: @LarrySnyder610 Due to [the way computers represent floating point numbers](https://youtu.be/pQs_wx8eoQ8) there *usually* will be some numbers that can't be represented. Rather than divulging the more complicated method, of an exact solution under all circumstances for 100 pennies, I was more interested in providing David a simple example that he could learn from.

Answer (score 0):

An answer with no $\epsilon$:

We can set $y+s=x $, $y \in \mathbb {Z} $, $s\geq 0$.

Appropriate terms (appropriate in terms of sign for following terms, values for big-M's and minimization and maximization) have to be added in the objective function such as $M_1x$, $M_2y$ based on the sign of $x$ in the objective function and bounds on $x$.

In the general case one can add these two terms somehow $x$ and $y$ have the same magnitude of increase in OF in both terms value and sign, if minimization $-M_1x$, $-M_2y$ and maximization $M_1x$, $M_2y$.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think this works either. $M$ could easily be large enough to force $x$ itself to be an integer, when it's not optimal (in the original problem) to do so. Example: $\min -x\ \text{s.t.}\ \lfloor x\rfloor \le 1,\ x\le 1.8$. Optimal solution is $x^*=1.8$ with objective $-1.8$. Your reformulation is: $\min -x + Ms\ \text{s.t.}\ y \le 1,\ x\le 1.8,\ y+s=x$. For sufficiently large $M$, optimal solution is $x^*=y^*=1$, $s^*=0$, objective $-1$.

Comment: And I don't think there's any way to set $M$ correctly *a priori* so we can be sure that the model will *first* optimize the "real" objective *and then* ensure that $s$ is as small as possible.

Comment: Agree, what if I set:$\min -x -M_1x-M_2y+ Ms\ \text{s.t.}\ y \le 1,\ x\le 1.8,\ y+s=x$, what is the optimal solution considering $ M_1,M_2 \ge \ge M$ ?

Comment: @LarrySnyder610 Correction:  $M_1,M_2>>M $

Comment: That might work in the specific case of my example (I haven't checked) but in general there is not (as far as I know) a way to set the coefficients *in general* that will ensure it works. Think about it this way: By adding a penalty $Ms$, you are essentially relaxing the constraint $s=0$ with a Lagrangian multiplier $M$. When you do so, you can't identify the optimal $M$ *a priori*; you'd need to use KKT conditions or an optimization over $M$, etc.

Comment: If you want to salvage this answer, I'd say it should explain exactly how to set the coefficients for *any* problem of the form $\min\ cx+dy,\ \text{s.t.} Ax+By=b,\ y=\lfloor x\rfloor,\ x\in\mathbb{R}$, where possibly $x$ and/or $y$ are vectors.

Comment: We can remove $Ms $ in case, in the question there is no sign of how $x $ is bounded or what is the sign of it's cost in O.F. So the answer still is correct. To enforce $y=\lfloor x \rfloor $ we need to add appropriate terms with $M $ in O.F.

Comment: I don't see how to apply your method in general, without extensive tuning of $M$. I agree it might be possible in some cases, but the question is to find a general method.

Comment: I have edited my answer according to the points your mentioning. The tuning of $M's $ is the easiest part.