# How to model y = floor(x)?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming

I went through the answers to this question: [Modeling floor function exactly](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/443/modeling-floor-function-exactly/513#513), but I still do not get how to model `y = floor(x)`. Is that question answered and I just do not see it?

Comment: You are essentially re-asking the same question, so I'd suggest that you ask a more specific version of your question, otherwise this one will probably get closed.

Comment: The short answer is that you cannot model a floor function exactly; it fails at the integer values of $x$.

Comment: Ok, now I get it. The whole discussion was about proving the statement "you cannot model a floor function exactly."

Comment: Hi, this is why I answered. I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

in https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/howtowithopl/blob/master/ceil.mod

```
    range r=1..4;

    float x[r]=[1.5,4.0,2.0001,5.9999];

    dvar int y[r];
    dvar float f[r] in 0..0.9999999;

    subject to
    {
    forall(i in r) y[i]==x[i]+f[i];


    }

    execute
    {
    writeln(x," ==> ",y);
    }

    assert forall(i in r) y[i]==ceil(x[i]);

//which gives

//    [1.5 4 2.0001 5.9999] ==>  [2 4 3 6]
```

I gave an OPL CPLEX example about how to model ceil. Floor is not very different.

> ```
> range r=1..4;
>
> float x[r]=[1.5,4.0,2.0001,5.9999];
>
> dvar int y[r];
> dvar float f[r] in 0..0.9999;
>
> subject to
> {
> forall(i in r) y[i]==x[i]-f[i];
>
>
> }
>
> execute
> {
> writeln(x," ==> ",y);
> }
>
> assert forall(i in r) y[i]==floor(x[i]);
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I tried finding floor value together with ceil value.
c = ceil(x) and f=floor(x)

$$x \leq c \leq x+1 $$
$$x \geq f \geq x-1 $$

$$ c-f \leq 1 $$
$$ x \leq f + M(c-x) $$
$$ x \geq c - M(x-f) $$
$$ x\in R^+, c,f \in Z^+ $$

Possible cases:
Case 1: x=3.9
$$3.9 \leq c \leq 4.9 $$
$$3.9 \geq f \geq 2.9 $$

$$ c-f \leq 1 $$
$$ 3.9 \leq f + M(c-3.9) $$
$$ 3.9 \geq c - M(3.9-f) $$
Result c=4, f=3

Case 2: x=3.1
$$3.1 \leq c \leq 4.1 $$
$$3.1 \geq f \geq 2.1 $$

$$ c-f \leq 1 $$
$$ 3.1 \leq f + M(c-3.1) $$
$$ 3.1 \geq c - M(3.1-f) $$
Result c=4, f=3

Case 3: x=3
$$3 \leq c \leq 4 $$
$$3 \geq f \geq 2 $$

$$ c-f \leq 1 $$
$$ 3 \leq f + M(c-3) $$
$$ 3 \geq c - M(3-f) $$
3.a. c=4, f=2 is possible from const 1 and 2 but const 3 inf.

3.b. c=4, f=3 is possible from const 1 and 2 but const 5 inf.

3.c. c=3, f=2 is possible from const 1 and 2 but const 4 inf.
Therefore c=3, f=3.

M is big number and determines the sensivity of x. For example, x=3.9 , M must be equal or greater than 10. Likewise, if x=3.99, $M \geq 100$

Comment: What prevents $(x,y)=(3,2)$?

Comment: @RobPratt I gave a new answer, I do not know there is something missed.

Comment: Your third constraint is implied by your first two constraints and can be omitted.  Also, Case 3 should have 3 instead of 3.1.

Comment: I think you will find that $1/M$ plays the same role as $\epsilon$ in the linked question.

Comment: You still need to replace 3,1 with 3 in Case 3.  And $(c,f)=(4,3)$ is feasible.

Comment: @RobPratt, the last const is written wrong, I fixed.

Comment: You still have a magic constant M which will cause problems. You don't even have a feasible solution for $x = 0.5\cdot \frac{1}{M}$, i.e. it will work at the integer cases, and for significantly non-integer, but then for close to integer it will not only yield the wrong result as is common in most naive models but simply be infeasible.